# Text Input shows blocks instead of Arabic Text in Flex Mobile Project

Tags: android, flash, ios, apache-flex, air

In Flex Mobile Project, Text Input shows blocks instead of showing arabic text. Labels are working fine with Arabic.

Is there any way to show Arabic text inside text input?

My code sample is

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    /* Import all the easing classes so its
    easier to switch between them on the
    fly without tweaking import statements. */
    import mx.effects.easing.*;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Style>
    @font-face {
    src: url('assets/AlBayan.ttf');
    font-family: Base02;
    unicode-range:
        U+0600-U+06FF,
        U+FB50-U+FDFF,
        U+FE70-U+FEFF;
    }

    .MyEmbeddedFont {
    font-family: Base02;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
</fx:Style>
<s:Label x="91" y="149" width="276" height="69" styleName="MyEmbeddedFont"
         text="Testing Unicodes"/>
<s:TextInput x="30" y="274" styleName="MyEmbeddedFont"/>
```

Since, it is for flex mobile project, when I input any text in arabic, it shows separate characters. Arabic is a language that doesn't have separate characters. It should combine letters to form specific word.

Comment: Are you using embedded fonts? Have you tried to set the locale to Arabic?

Comment: I tried both but no luck. I want to take input from user in Arabic so the TextInput must support arabic.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already embedded a font that supports Arabic characters, you can try adding the unicode ranges for those characters into your app. FlexEamples has a pretty good [write-up about it here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/specifying-certain-unicode-ranges-for-embedded-fonts/).

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="800" height="600">
        <mx:Style>
        @font-face {
            src: url('assets/fonts/TAHOMA.TTF');
            font-family: Base02;
            unicode-range:
                U+0600-U+06FF,
                U+FB50-U+FDFF,
                U+FE70-U+FEFF; /* define the character range, these ranges are for arabic */
        }

        .MyEmbeddedFont {
            font-family: Base02;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </mx:Style>
        <mx:TextInput id="embeddedText" text="¿¿¿¿¿" styleName="MyEmbeddedFont" fontAntiAliasType="advanced"/>
</mx:Application>
```

You may also want to take a look at [FlarabySWF](http://www.arabicode.com/flarabyswf/main). I haven't used it personally, but it may be worth investigating as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason. I am trying to integrate it with mobile projects and its not working fine.

Comment: @Imran What have you tried so far that's not working? Can you provide us with a code example?